# How to get rid of layer created by Make Feature Layer (Data Management)

Tags: arcpy

I like to run some scripts from mxd. Very often I am using *Make Feature Layer tool* to facilitate queries.

Tool help says:
“Creates a feature layer from an input feature class or layer file. The layer that is created by the tool is temporary and will not persist **after the session ends** unless the layer is saved to disk or the map document is saved”.

Question:

How to remove newly created layer without closing mxd?

Note **arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer** is not working on layer created that way or maybe I am doing something wrong here

Comment: Are you using the temporary layers for a purpose within ArcMap?  If you can just use them "in memory", maybe you can set the `arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False` so that they never get added in the first place.  Then when you terminate the ArcMap session the references should die too.

Comment: The partner function to RemoveLayer is AddLayer.  The partner to MakeFeatureLayer is Delete.

Comment: Will check delete tomorrow, looks like solution. Thanks

Comment: Confirmed  arcpy.Delete_management(lyr) works